# How to valid purchase express server using google-play-purchase-validator

Tags: android, node.js, express, unity-game-engine

I want integrating Google Play in-app billing to my unity project that already get payLoad json. I have a Node.js server and want to get value of the Google Play purchase response for server side verification.

My list product on Google Play Developer Console was create productId but i got error:

> [Error: The subscription purchase token does not match the
>   subscription ID.]

In my index.js file of my node server I have a segment like this:

```
var Verifier = require('google-play-purchase-validator');
var options = {
    email: '#############-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
    key: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----##some private key##-----END PRIVATE KEY-----',
    keyFile: './Google Play Android Developer-############.json'
};
var verifier = new Verifier(options);
var receipt = {
    packageName:"com.natekgames.######",
    productId:"com.natekgames.######.diamond_48",
    purchaseToken:"ihfeaepjoppolibmeknoghmo.AO-J1OxbHPDa8QLVAU3OqvIa-ZgaAGWhrBhs8DyCEfFbbdTCH8ecvEXQlZtjkqaowPXujb0Osn_aOWBPMT0OpTMcivoQalEtOZmMhS2lDA7oH868NjZP2LgdE9ODafujNM7O9QQr3-hq"
};
verifier.verify(receipt, function cb(err, response){
    if(err){
        console.log("there was an error validating the receipt");
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("sucessfully validated the receipt");
    res.send(response);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you are calling the subscriptions endpoint for subscriptions and the purchases endpoint for in-app purchases. Don't mix them, or you'll get this error.
2. Make sure the `productId` parameter is written exactly same way as it's written in Google Play Developer Console.